# Помогите с анимацией падающих звезд

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю анимацию падающих звезд (вид сверху). Каждая звезда - это `div`-элемент, использую `jQuery` для анимации (`animate`). Когда звезда долетает до некоторой области, ее нужно переместить вверх и снова запустить анимацию. Долетела звезда или нет - проверяю в таймере, но таймер с очень маленьким интервалом, и в нем производится обход всех элементов-звезд, для каждого из которых проверяется позиция (то есть, необходимость повторного запуска анимации).

Можно как-то здесь обойтись без таймера? Я знаю, что у метода `animate` есть `callback`-функция, может быть, ее как-то можно задействовать? Не приходит на ум, как использовать это для "бесконечной" (зацикленной) анимации.

Comment: А нельзя ли не проверять "границу", а вместо границы накрыть звезды другим блоком, чтобы без какой-либо проверки, все они просто уходили под него. А при завершении анимации - она бы просто перезапускалась.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, я еще произвожу некоторые действия перед запуском новой анимации - рассчитываю случайные позицию, размеры и уровень прозрачности. Автоматический перезапуск в этом случае не получится. Но они и сейчас уходят  "под блок", при помощи `overflow: hidden;`.